# Poor example question/answers on the Tour page

Tags: discussion

I happened to stumble across the [tour](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour) page today and read the example question and answers:

> [image: Low quality question and answers]

The tour page displays [this real question and a couple answers it received](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7400/should-double-click-be-avoided-in-web-applications) ~7 years ago. Is it just me or is this a poor example of both questions and answers on this site, based on our current standards?

Our help page [states the following](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> #### What makes a good question?
>
> We prefer questions that elicit definitive answers or solutions rather than prolonged discussions. Remember, this a Q&A site, not a discussion board.
>
> More context yields better answers. Fill your question with details such as:
>
> - Description of the users' experience levels and goals
> - Mockups, screenshots, or photos of existing designs
> - Software platform, if applicable (Is it an Android app? A web form? A kiosk with a 20"×20" touch screen?)

*Our own example question* satisfies none of these outlined criteria. The showcased answers are brief, unsupported opinions. I understand that the purpose of the tour page is to introduce the structure, function, and purpose of the site, so a brief example is preferred, but it seems a bit hypocritical. Perhaps this question and these answers were acceptable back then, but **is it time we consider selecting a new question with answers that reflect our current standards** or is the brevity valuable enough to keep this as our most visible example?

Comment: Good point. We have a moderator election coming up next week so updating this could be a good task for whomever comes onto the team. Any suggestions for a question it should be replaced with?

Comment: @JonW Pretty much any question I've answered would be great :) JK. I'll look for some options in a couple hours.